# Beginner PowerShell Scripting

Tags: powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, file-rename

All,

I am looking for a way to create a file every hour which captures the output of 24 commands.  These commands will output the status of replication for 24 consistency groups into the same file.  The file or the information in the file needs to be emailed to a DL.  My hangup seems to be on the file check.  If file exists rename/move, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need Test-Path command

```
$bool = Test-Path $fileName

if($bool){
 Rename-Item $fileName $newFileName
}
```